# What could i implement to learn .net GC in depth

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, implementation, depth

I know some details of how it works by Richter's book, but i want to "feel" it in practice. I see some variants:

1. Write my own GC implementation by .NET standard (just kidding, it is too hardcore to do it on my own :)
2. Study MONO implementation of GC - it have some pluses (for example i could analyze some cases with debugger), but on the other hand it is not so different from reading a book. And by the way as far as i know MONO implementation really differs from Microsoft's one (correct me if i am wrong).

So, any suggestions?

Comment: I concur, both Rotor and Mono have very different garbage collector implementations compared to the CLR GC. At the risk of sounding blatantly self-promoting, I think my book ("Pro .NET Performance", http://www.amazon.com/Pro-NET-Performance-Optimize-Applications/dp/1430244585) has more details on garbage collection than "CLR via C#".

Comment: This is not a question for SO.
(Where is the technical problem you trying to solve?)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could write a resource intensive server application, that will give you the gist of what GC does under significant load. You can pick anything you want, ideally something like a web server, an MMO server, etc.

You will get to see how the GC manages the managed heap under complicated circumstances (asynchronous sockets in particular make GC very unhappy, thanks to their use of pinned handles), and you can experiment with how to best allocate different kinds of memory resources to make GCs job as easy as possible.

And you could write your own GC, stupid GC is not *that* hard.